# OlEdB Exception was unhandled by usercode

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

I keep getting the above error when trying to enter my value from a dropdownlist and my value from a GridViewRow.

It also says "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Experession", I'm pulling the ID's of a Question and Paper from either the list/row and inputting them into my database.

Here's the code presenting the error.

```
Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim allCheckedRows = From row In CreateTest.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)()
                 Let chkQuestion = DirectCast(row.FindControl("QuestionSelector"), CheckBox)
                 Where chkQuestion.Checked
                 Select row
    For Each checkedRow As GridViewRow In allCheckedRows

        Dim QuestionID As String = (checkedRow.Cells(0).Text)

        Dim PaperID As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

        Dim insertExamQuery = "INSERT INTO QuestionInPaper VALUES ('QuestionID', 'PaperID');"

        Dim insertExamCmd = con.CreateCommand()
        insertExamCmd.CommandText = insertExamQuery
        insertExamCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next
End Using
```

Here's the aspx all of this refers to:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CreateTest" runat="server" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="QuestionID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="QuestionSelector" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QuestionID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="QuestionID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer" HeaderText="Answer" 
            SortExpression="Answer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
            SortExpression="Question" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubjectID" HeaderText="SubjectID" 
            SortExpression="SubjectID" />
        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [QuestionID], [Answer], [Question], [SubjectID] FROM [Question]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="PaperID" DataValueField="PaperID">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Can you see where this mismatch is? ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is `INSERT INTO QuestionInPaper VALUES ('QuestionID', 'PaperID');` , Can i see table named `QuestionInPaper` in detail ?

Comment: I can't post pictures but QuestionInPaper is a breaker between two other tables to store the two pieces of data, Both PaperID and QuestionID inside of the QuestionInPaper are Numeric data types, they are the only two fields inside of the table.

Comment: According to your comment, I assume that you are trying to insert integer value column to varchar value.
Please try something like that `INSERT INTO QuestionInPaper VALUES (1, 1);`. I mean you just replace Insert statement by using corrected integer value

Comment: Same problem, same error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying both your fields in QuestionInPaper are Numeric type, yet you are trying to insert string data - 'QuestionID' and 'PaperID'. You need to add them as parameters to your command. Also you are creating them as String, both types in code and database should be equal.

```
    Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("ConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim allCheckedRows = From row In CreateTest.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)()
                     Let chkQuestion = DirectCast(row.FindControl("QuestionSelector"), CheckBox)
                     Where chkQuestion.Checked
                     Select row
        For Each checkedRow As GridViewRow In allCheckedRows

            '// change type and parse
            Dim QuestionID As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(checkedRow.Cells(0).Text)
            Dim PaperID As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)

            '// changed
            Dim insertExamQuery = "INSERT INTO QuestionInPaper (QuestionID, PaperID) VALUES (?, ?);"

            Dim insertExamCmd = con.CreateCommand()

            '// added below
            insertExamCmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", OleDb.OleDbType.Numeric).Value = QuestionID
            insertExamCmd.Parameters.Add("@PaperID", OleDb.OleDbType.Numeric).Value = PaperID
            '// end add

            insertExamCmd.CommandText = insertExamQuery
            insertExamCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it's really really appreciated but I'm still getting this error:

Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: This was when declaring the questionID

Comment: So, this line is causing errors? Dim QuestionID As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(checkedRow.Cells(0).Text). Can you check what checkedRow contains when you step into For Each?

Comment: If checkedRow is Nothing then there is no loop, how can you get an error at declaring QuestionID? Also what value is in the first column of the GridView? I'm assuming Decimal.Parse fails because there is a string instead of a numeric type.

Comment: Thank you! Gave me a tiny brainwave, I was being stupid enough to set the value to 0, which actually referred to a checkbox, once I set it to 1, it obviously reffered to the QuestionID, I assumed because the checbox was inside of a ListItem refrencing the QuestionID as 0 would be correct, but again thank you!